# Type casting node structure to print content

Tags: c, casting

I am writing a binary tree program where each node in the tree contains a struct.
I am stuck on how to properly type cast the struct in order to print it's contents.

This is my struct definition:

```
//inventory definition
typedef struct inventory
{
    char invName[36];
    int  invPartNo;
    int  invQOH;
    float invUnitCost;
    float invPrice;
}item;

//tree definition
struct btree {
    void *data;
    struct btree *left;
    struct btree *right;
} ;
```

And in here I am trying to type cast the struct contents so I can print it:

```
void print_inorder(btree *node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    print_inorder((struct btree*)node->left);

    //error here in these 5 lines: the node->data->invName, invPartNo, etc.
    printf("Name: %s\n", (char)node->data->invName); //my incorrect attempt
    printf("Part Number: %.5d\n", (int*)node->data->invPartNo);
    printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", node->data->invQOH);
    printf("Unit Cost: %0.2f\n", node->data->invUnitCost);
    printf("Price %0.2f\n\n", node->data->invPrice);

    print_inorder(node->right);
}
```

Comment: the five print functions, i do not know how to type cast it into a string, int, etc to print it.

Comment: How can you access elements of `item` from a void pointer `data`? you need to change `void *data` to `item *data` in `struct btree` OR you need to typecast whole `data` pointer to `item` pointer first. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suppose that you are having compilation errors.

Don't hesitate to use more brackets and you forgot to cast `void*` to `item*`:

```
printf("Name: %s\n", ((item*)(node->data))->invName);
printf("Part Number: %.5d\n", ((item*)(node->data))->invPartNo);
printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", ((item*)(node->data))->invQOH);
printf("Unit Cost: %0.2f\n", ((item*)(node->data))->invUnitCost);
printf("Price %0.2f\n\n", ((item*)(node->data))->invPrice);
```

Comment: Why don't you use a local `item*` variable? It will be far easier to write and read.

Answer (score 1):

Define a (temporary) pointer to what you expect under the `void`-pointer:

```
item * pitem = node->data;
```

Test if it is pointing to something and print it:

```
if (NULL != pitem)
{
  printf("Name: %s\n", pitem->invName); 
  printf("Part Number: %.5d\n", pitem->invPartNo);
  printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", pitem->invQOH);
  printf("Unit Cost: %0.2f\n", pitem->invUnitCost);
  printf("Price %0.2f\n\n", pitem->invPrice);
}
```

or assert if it's not valid:

```
assert(NULL != pitem);

printf("Name: %s\n", pitem->invName); 
printf("Part Number: %.5d\n", pitem->invPartNo);
printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", pitem->invQOH);
printf("Unit Cost: %0.2f\n", pitem->invUnitCost);
printf("Price %0.2f\n\n", pitem->invPrice);
```